# Get Folder path using React js

Tags: reactjs, directory

I want to get path of the folder so that i need to post the path of the selected folder to the backend so it receives like this

```
string path2 = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\workspace\");
```

I tried `<input directory="" webkitdirectory=""  type="file" />`it doesn't show the path of the folder it just shows like `foldername/filename.jpg` i want the path like `C:\Users\Public\Desktop\workspace\` kindly guide me how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that in React, if you still want to get the file path I would suggest you doing **Electron** and use **fs** inside the Electron.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do so - the browser will not allow this because of security concerns.

> When a file is selected by using the input type=file object, the value of the value property depends on the value of the "Include local directory path when uploading files to a server" security setting for the security zone used to display the Web page containing the input object.

> The fully qualified filename of the selected file is returned only when this setting is enabled. When the setting is disabled, Internet Explorer 8 replaces the local drive and directory path with the string C:\fakepath\ in order to prevent inappropriate information disclosure.

See https://webplatform.github.io/docs/html/elements/input/type/file/ for more info about this.

Answer (score 0):

in react js I just want to know the filenames so i just simply use the file target function

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
const [filename, setFileName] = useState([]);

const handle = (event) => {
const data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {
  data.push(event.target.files[i]);
}

console.log("data :- ", data);
setFileName(data);
};

return (
<div className="App">
  <h1>Hello...</h1>

  <input type="file" onChange={handle} multiple />

  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">File name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    {fileName.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <React.Fragment key={i}>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">{i}</th>
              <td>{item.name}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    })}
  </table>
</div>
);
}
```